# Use Linq instead of nested foreach loops to sum values

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find the sum of values without using a nested foreach loop

How do I write this using Linq instead?

```
decimal posVal = 0;
decimal negVal = 0;
foreach (var j in journal)
{
    foreach (var t in j.trans)
    {
        foreach (var l in t.line)
        {
            if (l.val > 0)
                posVal += l.val;
            else
                negVal += l.val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach (var l in journal.SelectMany(j => j.trans).SelectMany(t => t.line)) { .. }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8),

```
var allLines = journal
               .SelectMany(j => j.trans
               .SelectMany(l => l.line)
               .ToList();

var posVal = allLines.Where(x => x.val > 0).Sum(x => x.val);
var negVal = allLines.Where(x => x.val < 0).Sum(x => x.val);
```

Comment: A couple of questions (disclaimer: I may be wrong since it's pre-morning coffee); Doesn't this just sum up the number of positives and negatives, not the values? Also, if my caffeine is not dangerously low it enumerates the enumerable twice, so if journal is not possible to enumerate more than once, it'll break.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Good morning ;) For first question, Yes I updated answer now it will sum up all values instead of positive, negatives. for second question, can you please elaborate I did not understand what you want convey here. As `journal` used in foreach loop it should be enumerate right? *if journal is not possible to enumerate more than once, it'll break.* please elaborate

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2019.1/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html has a pretty good explanation. Let's for example say that `journal` is an enumerable that reads the data from the database. If so, calculating `posVal` and `negVal` will ask the database once each, possibly with different results if the database is updated inbetween. It may be quite ok if journal is for example a list, but in this case we don't really know for sure :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, thanks for this article, I understood and updated my answer. Now I am forcing enumeration while initializing `allLines` variable, in this way it will not give two different results if `journal` updates in between `posVal` and `negVal`.

Comment: I was not aware of this, thanks for helping me here, Have a nice day

Comment: now you iterating over `IEnumerable` three times instead of two (where you actually can iterate only once) :\ this is highly inefficient

Comment: @vasily.sib, I updated my answer, Now I am first converting `journal` to `List` and then converting `allLines` to one sequence.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar you just made it even worse:) For example, if your `journal` is fetching data from DB you firstly get **ALL** data from DB and then filter it on client side. So if `journal` has 10M records in DB - you transfer all this 10M records over your network, store this 10M of objects in memory and only then apply filter. Things will getting even more worse if there is a relations in `journal` objects

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar and you still do not take into account the enumerated nature of `IEnumerable`. What if `journal.val` returning different values each time you read it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196029/discussion-between-prasad-telkikar-and-vasily-sib).